# Как явно вызвать метод OnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть список `ListView`, который отрабатывает нажатия методом

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3)
{
    //алгоритм
}
```

Долго объяснять зачем, но как вызвать обработку нажатия из конструктора.(Явный вызов)

Comment: Вам нужна прграммная эмуляция нажатия на элемент списка? И из какого конструктора вы хотите вызвать эту обработку нажатия? Постарайтесь задать вопрос так, чтобы он был понятен не только вам, но и другим тоже. Это сильно увеличит ваши шансы получить правильный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понял условие, необходимо воспользоваться следующим методом `ListView`:

> public boolean performItemClick (View view, int position, long id)

Пример вызова:

```
mList.performItemClick(
        mList.getAdapter().getView(mActivePosition, null, null),
        mActivePosition,
        mList.getAdapter().getItemId(mActivePosition));
```

Данный метод эмитирует нажатие на элемент в позиции `mActivePosition`.

Answer (score 0):

Создать объект OnItemClickListener, например:

```
OnItemClickListener listener =  new OnItemClickListener(){
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
             {
             ...
             }
}
```

Ну и где нужно:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
```

P.S.: гугл в помощь